# How to combine short dragging and long press

Tags: iphone

I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer with minimumPressDuration to 0.5. I need it for fast dragging. Now I also want to detect when a user makes a long press without moving the fingers for more than few seconds. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Your `UIView` will have to adopt this protocol and implement `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer` method. If you have only this two recognizers attached you can simply return `YES`.

Don't forget to set your `UIView` as a `delegate` of both `UIGestureRecognizers`.